# SASS lighten darker issue using with :root

Tags: css, sass

I am create root css variables to change color dynamic and use this variables in scss but it's not working.

I am trying this solution:

```
:root {
  --primary-admin: #282828;
  --primary-light-20: lighten(var(--primary-admin), 20%);
  --primary-light-30: lighten(var(--primary-admin), 30%);
  --primary-light-40: lighten(var(--primary-admin), 40%);
  --primary-light-60: lighten(var(--primary-admin), 60%);
  --primary-light-70: lighten(var(--primary-admin), 70%);
  --primary-darken-20: darken(var(--primary-admin), 20%);
}
```

```
$primary-color: var(--primary-admin);
$primary-light-20: var(--primary-light-20); 
$primary-light-30: var(--primary-light-30); 
$primary-light-40: var(--primary-light-40); 
$primary-light-60: var(--primary-light-60); 
$primary-light-70: var(--primary-light-70);
$primary-darken-20: var(--primary-darken-20);
$primary-color: var(--primary-admin);

body {
  background-color: var(--color-primary-darker);
}
```

Comment: you cannot use CSS variables in Sass